# do i have every time to change the database number even if i did not make any changes to my database structure to be published to google play store

Tags: android, google-play, sqliteopenhelper

I have published my android app in google play store it works fine and perfect(my app first will go and create a sqlite DB using SQLiteOpenHelper class then the index.html page will be displayed) then i noticed that users with android version 2.3.6 have error when they install the app i solved the problem without changing or adding to the structure of the DB then after publishing the new version of my app without changing the version of the database my app will not show the index.html and i think it will keep trying creating the database and the user will just see the loading message only. 
So do i have every time to change the database number even if i did not make any changes to my database structure to be published to google play store.

Answer (score 1):

No, you only change the database version number to a higher version ONLY if you change the structure of the database or decide to automatically add data.


For example, you can start with version 1 with a database that contains only one table: let's call it `User`, and the table has a column called `Username`. You run the query to create the table on your `onCreate` method. Then you release the app.


Then you decide to add more features to the app, and implement a version of the app that did not require any database changes at all. Your db version stays 1.


Then on your next app version, you decide to add a column to the `User` table. So what you do, is increment the db version to 2, and then run the `alter table` statement on your `onUpgrade` method. Then you release the app.


I believe your issue lies somewhere else. Check your database data integrity and that it fits your app's model.

Comment: it will be better if can also show how to execute `Alter` command in the `onUpgrade` method. Thanks.